# in SVN is there a command to view where the code has been checked out to?

Tags: svn

Basically, I want a listing of all places SVN code has been checked out to. 
Does subversion track this?
I can do "SVN ls", that shows me what's in the report, but not where all it has been checked out to.

Comment: Were you looking for SVN working copies on your computer or did you want to know who and when checked out a working copy from the repository on a server? I.e. was it for access audit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subversion does not track this in the same way that Notepad doesn't track every file that it has ever saved.  It's a client application that operates at most on the current directory.

The best you can do is search your disk for *.svn* folders. Assuming your SVN client is at least version 1.7 then [each *.svn* folder will correspond to a single checkout](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#wc-ng):

> ... Subversion 1.7 working copies have just one .svn directory—in the root of the working copy.